# In an onchange event, can you pass parameters that are not the current control?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a function:

```
function passSomeParams(p0, p1) {
    window.Location.href = "/something/anotherthing.aspx?firstParam=" +
        p0 + "&secondParam=" + p1;
}
```

Can I pass inputs other than the current control? I wanted to do something like this below, but wasn't able to get it to work or find resources online mentioning if it was possible or not.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkCheckboxA" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkCheckboxB"
    onchange="passSomeParams(this.value, chkCheckboxA.value)"/>
```

Thanks. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes you can. Have you tried it?

Comment: `chkCheckboxA` would be `undefined` as it's not a `DOM object`. If you really need to do the way you did, `document.getElementById('chkCheckboxA').value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be done the way you did, using `inline event handler`, then you can do it the following ways. But there are better ways!

```
function passSomeParams1(v1, v2) {    
    //Option 1
    var param1 = v1;
    var param2 = v2;
    // --;
}
function passSomeParams2(v1, v2) { 
    //Option 2
    var param1 = document.getElementById(v1).value;
    var param2 = document.getElementById(v2).value;
    // --;
}
```

Without `inline event handler`:

```
document.getElementById('second').addEventListener("change", function() {
    //Option 3
    var param1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var param2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
    // --;
});
```

jQuery:

```
$('#second').on("change", function() {
    //Option 4
    var param1 = $(this).val();
    var param2 = $("#first").val();
    // --;
});
```

HTML (sample)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="first" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="second" value="2" onchange="passSomeParams1(this.value, document.getElementById('first').value)"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="first" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="second" value="2" onchange="passSomeParams2(this.id, 'first')"/>
```